# Yii2 Error response jsono header?

Tags: php, ajax, yii2

Hi i have problem with pagination in  linkerPage.

My problem https://gyazo.com/cc9b04c3114d6cfd09ef376b5d4374ac

I use https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-tabs-x

when i want using pagination I gets raw html, how on the screen. 
My console browser shows error

"Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/json:" {my url}
  My controller

```
    public function actionTestTabs()
{


    Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;


        $MovieData = seanse::find()->innerJoinWith(['idMovie', 'idRoom']
        )->where(['active' => 'active'])
            ->groupBy('name');
        $date = seanse::find()->innerJoinWith(['idMovie', 'idRoom']
        )->where(['active' => 'active'])
            ->orderBy('name')->all();

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $MovieData,
            'pagination' => [
                'totalCount' => 1,
                'pageSize' => 1,

            ],

        ]);


        return $this->renderPartial('test', [
            'MovieData' => $MovieData,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'date' => $date,



        ]);

}
```

My view

```
foreach ($month as $item) {


$items[] = [

    'label' => $item,
    'linkOptions' => ['data-url' => Url::to(['repertuar/test-tabs'])],

];
}

echo TabsX::widget([
'align' => TabsX::ALIGN_CENTER,
'items' => $items,


]);
```

what is wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Whats the problem? You've setted "json" response header in line:

```
Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
```

Just remove this line from code or comment it.

Comment: I can't comment  because i load through  ajax  content.